# Java global keypress?

Tags: java, keypress

For my program i need to register key events that happen without the application having the focus. (i.e. internet explorer having the focus) I have been looking and people say you can do it with jni; however, is there anyway to do it without it?

Can someone give me a link of a really good jni example? the ones i have looked at so far havent been very helpful

Answer (score 2):

JIntellitype (which is an Apache 2.0 license) will do this for you in Windows.  JxGrabKey appears to be a valid solution for Linux.  I'm not aware of a cross-platform solution.  (These still use JNI, but they'll abstract the details for you)

http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/index.html

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jxgrabkey/

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to create a key logger? No, it is not possible without JNI or using some library which wraps the JNI away for you.

The only way in Java to do things outside of your own Frames/Windows is using java.awt.Robot, but this only allows screenshots and sending input to other programs, not capturing input.

Comment: No im not making a keylogger, I am making an auto clicking program where whenever i press the F7 key, the computer stores the mouse cooardinates to be user later with the robot class. I looked at some jni examples but i didnt find any really helpful ones. Could you maybe point me in the right direction?

Comment: I've never really done JNI, as then the program inherently gets system dependent. So I can't really help you here, sorry.